# Django doesn't creates objects for all rows in postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm scripting a migration tool to get my data from an old software to a new version with different data structures.

While looping through the csv-files I'm creating the objects.
The problem is that every object gets created in postgres but django doesn't.

I'm getting errors like:
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "api_order_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(159865) already exists.

Order.objects.get(pk=159865) does return "Does not exist"
But a SELECT * FROM api_order WHERE pk = 159865 directly in Postgres finds a row.

```
with open("order.csv","r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        Order.objects.create(pk = row[0], ordernr= row[1],....)`
```

thats of course a short version of it.

On the import of about 250.000 rows this problem appears with about 100 rows.

I had the same problem with deleting. I ran Order.objects.all().delete() but in Postgres there where still a few rows left while Order.objects.all() returned an empty Queryset.

Is there something I can do about this?
Has anyone had a similar problem?

Comment: share you model

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my fault.

I had a Manager running which was modifying the queryset.
Thats why Django did not show all records.